# Converting overloaded function is ambiguous

Tags: c++, gcc, type-conversion, function-pointers, overloading

I have an issue where creating a function pointer to an overloaded function results in a compile error on g++ 4.7 and g++ 4.8 but not on g++ 4.4, g++ 4.6 or clang++ 3.2 (and possibly VS2010).

Having googled around a bit to find out whether the issue is with g++ or with my code, I still can't decide.
Are the overload resolution rules that apply to function pointer conversion different than those that apply to function calls?

This is a somewhat minimized code that demonstrates the issue:

```
template < class T >
struct Dummy {
    typedef T value_type;
    value_type value;
};

template < class T >
typename T::value_type f (const T& x) {
    return x.value;
}

template < class T >
T f (Dummy< T > const& x) {
    return x.value + 1;
}

int main (int, char**) {
    Dummy< int > d = { 1 };
    // No ambiguity here
    d.value = f(d);
    // This is ambiguous for *some* compilers
    int (* const f_ptr)(Dummy< int > const&) = f;
    return f_ptr( d );
}
```

clang++ 3.2, g++ 4.4 and g++ 4.6 compile this with `-Wall -pedantic --std=c++98` without warnings.

g++ 4.7 and g++ 4.8 however give the following error message:

```
test.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
test.cc:15:45: error: converting overloaded function ‘f’ to type ‘int (* const)(const struct Dummy<int>&)’ is ambiguous
test.cc:6:18: error: candidates are: typename T::Type f(const T&) [with T = Dummy<int>; typename T::Type = int]
test.cc:9:3: error:                 T f(const Dummy<T>&) [with T = int]
```

Is this an issue with newer versions of g++ or is my code in fact wrong?

If it is, how would one go about resolving such an ambiguity?

Comment: Here is a thing to try: comment out one f(), compile the file. Comment out the other f(), compile the file. The kind of result you'll get should clarify this situation quite a bit.

Comment: @Arkadiy are you suggesting that this is an indication that the result should be an ambiguity?

Comment: If the source compiles with either function commented out, then I'd say there is at leas a strong possibility they are ambiguous. If either function satisfies the requirement then we'd have to have a preference for one of them to avoid ambiguity, and no preference suggests itself, at least on first impression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> > Is this an issue with newer versions of g++ or is my code in fact wrong?

I guess this is legal code (but I'm not so sure). To add to the list: it does compile with clang 3.3 and icc 13.1.3.

> > how would one go about resolving such an ambiguity?

You can use

```
    int (* const f_ptr)(Dummy< int > const&) = f<int>;
```

to select the second overload or

```
    int (* const f_ptr)(Dummy< int > const&) = f<Dummy<int> >;
```

to select the first one.

If you don't want to manually disambiguate (like my suggestion above) I can suggest a workaround that uses SFINAE to disambiguate. I'm assuming you can use C++11 (default template arguments for function templates) but I believe with some extra work it can be extended to C++98.

Change the definitions of `f` to:

```
template < class T, class R = typename T::value_type>
R f (const T&) {
    return x.value;
}

template < class T, class R = T>
R f (Dummy< T > const&) {
    return x.value + 1;
}
```

With this, the original line (below) compiles fine in gcc (4.7.3 and 4.8.1):

```
int (* const f_ptr)(Dummy< int > const&) = f;
```